# How do I sort an array in a swift dictionary?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary where the objects are arrays. What is the best or proper way to then sort that array?

Here is the dictionary:

```
var sections:[String:[SomeStruct]] = [:]
```

EDIT:

I went this way,

```
    for key in sections.keys {
        sections[key]?.sort{$0.name < $1.name}
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to sort each array as you add the key/value to the dictionary or do you want to sort each array at a later time?

Comment: BTW - sorting is easy enough. What have you tried and what issue are you having? Please update your question with relevant details.

Comment: the array of the struct need to be sorted later on an attribute. I thought there might be some cool syntax like @4castle below, though that error out.

Comment: This is why you need to update your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort each array in a mutable dictionary like this:

```
for key in sections.keys {
    sections[key]?.sort(by: >)
}
```

Comment: Thank you I couldn't find that syntax anywhere.

Comment: Ambiguous reference to member '>'

Comment: Probably because your `SomeStruct` doesn't conform to `Comparable`.

Comment: I was trying to find a one liner I thought I saw somewhere awhile ago. I now realize I was stupid thinking they were comparable, and thought your little by: > was the answer. I will remember that next imte

Comment: You can also use Swift 4 mapValues method `sections = sections.mapValues({$0.sorted()})`